# place data into a hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `onSelect` method from a dropdown menu so when a user selects `FirstOption` he should get a value of `1`. At the end I have output which picks one of the selected option.

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.SelectID').click(function (e) { 
   var output;
        var select = $(this);
        switch (select.text()){
            case "FirstOption":
                var a = ("1");
                break;
            case "SecondOption":
                var b = ("2");
                break;
        }
        output = [a|| b];
    }

    <input id="text" type="hidden" />
```

I also have a hidden field, My question is how do i store output in that hidden field so i can use that value in another function.

Comment: There's no need to store values in hidden fields unless you intend to submit them. If you just want to use the value in another function why don't you put it in a variable declared in a scope that both functions can access (e.g., a local variable in your ready handler)?

Comment: can you share the html sample also... if possible create a sample in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: if you are using a select box why don't you just put the values in the option tag itself instead of doing all this logic? something like `<option val="1">FirstOption</option>`. I don't know whats stopping you from doing this.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes i will be submiting this value to search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign value to hidden add give id to your hidden field and then using jquery assign value like this
$("#id").val(value to be assigned);

You make also use global variable for this purpose.